# AnySite - Export Spreadsheet of Multiple Demographic Points

Tags: mapinfo, excel

I have a point file of every single intersection in my city. I'd like to be able to run demographics on EVERY SINGLE POINT and have the demographic data for intersection  go into a single master spreadsheet.

AnySite will create a report for each point on an individual basis, but I need all that data from each of those reports in one big spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by choosing File>New>Batch within Anysite.  You can open your point layer file, & your radius or drive time preferences.  Then at the bottom of the box choose "Combine Reports".  Now run your report & it will all be output into one file.